# How to do PHP FB Login with DannyBTran CodeIgniter Facebook Library

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

Currently I am using the CodeIgniter (CI) Library from DannyBTran

```
https://github.com/dannybtran/CI_Facebook
```

to tie together Facebook and a PHP application.

I have been playing around with many different FB Libraries to tether it together with PHP but where one has great explanations in one area, in the other areas I am completely lost. In this Library ***I don't understand how to do a FB Connect feature or find a way for a user to log in using Facebook and have their userid be carried over into the CI Library.***

I have already looked over most of the Facebook Developer Pages and after a point get lost as well...

The documentation on the authentication page I understand

```
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/
```

***But I don't know how to make that information I grab from the User logging in talk to the new CodeIgniter library.***

Just as a reference point other Libraries I have tried implementing were

```
http://www.haughin.com/code/facebook/
-----------------
http://junal.wordpress.com/2008/01/20/a-sample-facebook-application-with-codeigniter/
-----------------
http://www.simpleprojectz.com/2008/10/facebook-codeigniter/
-----------------
http://www.allfacebook.com/facebook-connect-codeigniter-2009-05
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

which type of application are you trying to do? Maybe you don't need to use that kind of library.

Here you have a very simple model for CI that explains some stuff: http://www.dannyherran.com/2011/02/facebook-php-sdk-and-codeigniter-for-basic-user-authentication/
In my opinion, using Facebook PHP class directly is much easier.

I don't quite understand if your problem is getting the information after logging in, or if it's to login. Please give us more information so we can help.

Comment: You rock! I will try the provided guide out in the following days. It seems to be very informational!